# Working with laravel dynamic data and lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel-5.4

My goal is to have an image gallery page that displays images in a modal when users click on a picture and be able to view other pictures by clicking on the left and right arrows. I'm attempting to achieve this with [lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). I have added lighbox.css and lightbox.js to my laravel project and my view renders properly but when i click on an image in chromo, the image opens fully in the same tab so that i don't have that modal effect. From the console i see this warning message

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/albums/albumImg/ckmUU5_album_image.png".

This is the first time I'm doing anything like this with laravel, so i haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is the code i have below

```
<div class="card-columns mb-5" id="albumImgs">

@foreach($album->photos as $photo)

    <div class="card">

        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/images/albums/albumImg/{{$photo->image}}" data-lightbox="photos">

            <img class="card-img" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/images/albums/albumImg/{{$photo->image}}" alt="">

        </a>

    </div>

@endforeach

</div>
```

I need help figuring out what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The issue was caused by the jquery file, bootstrap 4 ships with the jquery slim version by default and it does not have the fadeIn function. Changing the cdn to jquery.min was all i did and my goal has been achieved. I hope this helps someone out there.